# Passing dynamic argument to event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I want to pass the dynamic argument to the click handlers. `ClassResult` make the ajax call and get the array of result and below I had passed the props to another component `StudentResult`. Now I want to get that props in click event handlers.

### Code:

```
class ClassResult extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {terminal: 'Select Terminal', class : 'Select Class'};
     this.state = {
        result: []
   };

 return(){
    render(
         {this.state.result.map((post, i) =><StudentResult key={i} name={post.STDNAME} roll={post.STROLLNO} om={post.STDTOTALOM} division={post.STDDIVGRADE} percent={post.STPERCENTAGE} remarks={post.STREMAKRS} schoolid={post.SCHOOLID} regno={post.REGNO}/>)}

  }
}


class StudentResult extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
    this.state = {fail : ''};
    this.displayDetailResult = this.displayDetailResult.bind(this, schoolid, regno);
   }

   displayDetailResult(e, schoolid, regno){
     //How to get schoolid and regno here

     alert(schoolid);
   }

   render() {
     if(this.props.percent < 50) {
              this.setState({fail : 'table-danger'});
            } else {
                this.setState({fail : ''});
            } 
  return (


            <tr className={this.state.fail} onClick={(e) => this.displayDetailResult(e, this.prop.schoolid, this.prop.regno)}>
                <td>{ this.props.name }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.roll }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.om }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.division }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.percent }</td>
                <td>{ this.props.remarks }</td>
            </tr>

  )
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion. setting state inside render method is a big mistake. leads to infinite loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are binding `displayDetailResult` in the constructor.

You have written

```
this.displayDetailResult = this.displayDetailResult.bind(this, schoolid, regno);
```

and henere `schoolid` and `regno` are not available,

You just need to write

```
this.displayDetailResult = this.displayDetailResult.bind(this);
```

and

call it like

```
<tr className={this.state.fail} onClick={this.displayDetailResult}>
```

and then in the displayDetailResult function you will have

```
displayDetailResult(e){
     console.log(this.props.schoolid, this.props.regno)
   }
```